# SonarQube (SonarLint /Sonar-JAVA) Redundant casts should not be used

Tags: java, casting, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I just stepped over some old code and did a SonarLint analysis. I cannot paste the code here but basically it is similar to:

```
Object test = new Object[]{"1"};
System.out.println(((Object[])test)[0]);
```

This very simple example works, but SonarLint reports an issue on 
**squid:S1905 - Redundant casts should not be used**

Any ideas why?

Comment: What are the version of SonarLint and SonarJava used ? do you use it in connected ore standalone mode ?

Comment: SonarLint 2.5.1 in connected mode to SonarQube 5.6.3, sonar-java 4.2.1.6971

Comment: Please update to latest version of SonarJava ( 4.5 at time of writing) and tell us if problem persists.

Comment: Hi, updated to 4.5.0.8398, still the same...

Answer (score 0):

Unless your reproduction snippet does not exactly mimic the real code, it's a false positive. The cast to `Object[]` is not redundant, but required. If this is the case, just ignore the issue as a false positive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can mark this as a false positive but since this is always reproducible I might report it as a bug.